# Can I omit the "it had" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> The beach looked as dazzling as (it had) from the highway.

The sentence is past-tense narration. Do I need the "it had"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The beach looked as dazzling up close as it had from the highway.**

I find removing the "it had" awkward if not downright ungrammatical because the shift of tense to the past perfect ("as it had *looked*", ellipsis) makes clear the temporal sequence of events, and dropping "it had" which already is an ellipsis would be an ellipsis of an ellipsis.

But:

**The statue looks as good on the shelf as on the mantelpiece.**

is less jarring (to me) because the tenses are the same, so we don't need "it does" as much as we need "it had" in the first sentence.

P.S. We could readily imagine a scenario where the statue had first been placed on the mantelpiece and then moved to the shelf, in which case a shift of tenses would be appropriate and then an "it did" would be asked for, if not demanded.  The timeline is more apparent in the example with the beach, where it is usually seen first as one approaches from the road, and then on foot after one gets out of the car.

Answer (score 1):

You use as...as when you compare one thing, person, or situation with the other such as "The beach looked as dazzling as the sun from the highway".

I am at a loss why we should use 'it had" in the sentence.

It's also correct to say "The beach looked so dazzling from the highway".